# maven artifact version does match with definition in jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a project pom with dependencies(reported by `mvn dependency:tree`) like this:

```
[INFO] +- com.gttown:gttown-dao-enterprise:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.gttown:gt-common-mybatis:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mybatis.generator:mybatis-generator-core:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.gttown:gt-common-util:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

It depends on `gttown-dao-enterprise 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` which indirectly depends on `gt-common-util 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. But I do define version of `gt-common-util` in `gttown-dao-enterprise 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` as 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<artifactId>gttown-dao-enterprise</artifactId>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gttown</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-common-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
</dependencies>
```

Theoretically the final version appears in project pom should be 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, how does maven analyze it as 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 0):

com.gttown:gt-common-mybatis depends of gttown-dao-enterprise 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT so maven resolve it with this version you can exclude in your pom, maven will take 1.0.0-SNPASHOT instead.

```
<artifactId>gttown-dao-enterprise</artifactId>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.gttown</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-common-mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>com.gttown</groupId>
          <artifactId>gt-common-util</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```